# SQL comparing when variable has list value and if its null

Tags: sql, mysql, list

i've been researching as to how will i solve this problem but none have worked so far. I have a query that will select all items when the variable's value is NULL.

Initially I have variable, {CustomerId} which can be a list or null value and will be used on this query:

`SELECT * FROM store WHERE ({CustomerId} IS NULL OR customer_id in {CustomerId}`

it works when {CustomerId} is NULL or for example (1). However when it takes a list (1, 2) i get an error because (1, 2) IS NULL is not a valid expression. I hope i can learn what can i do with this problems here. Thanks!

Comment: *"`{CustomerId}` which can be a list or null value"* does this `{CustomerId}` come from your own program? something written in general purpose programming language. i think it would be far easier to tackle the problem from there rather than concocting questionable hacky sql.

Comment: Do you simply insert the variable value into the query text immediately? this is a way to the SQL injection. Use prepared statement.. *when it takes a list (1, 2) i get an error because (1, 2) IS NULL is not a valid expression.* Enclose your value with single quotes and test that final string literal is equal to `'NULL'`.

Comment: @BagusTesa {CustomerId} is a variable from a software Stimulsoft Designer, any values can be entered to the variable

Comment: @Akina if i make it into a string, how will i use it on customer_id IN ({CustomerId})

Comment: ?? In one place you insert with quotes, in another one - without them.

Comment: @David you were withholding important information. you should tag this question with [tag:stimulsoft] to draw relevant experts. also, what @Akina meant perhaps something like `SELECT * FROM store WHERE ('{CustomerId}' = 'null' OR customer_id in {CustomerId}` - but i cant be sure whether stimulsoft will use `'NULL'`, `'Null'` or `'null'`.

Comment: What a problem? Specify case-independent collation explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you @Akina and @Bagus Tesa, I solved the issue by using this:

```
SELECT * FROM store 
WHERE ('{CustomerId}' = 'null' OR customer_id in {CustomerId})
```

sorry for misunderstanding the explanation of the solution.